# SQL statement to retrieve the last filled column value as result

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

Using the below sql statement to get the last filled column from a table fields but not getting it to work.

```
select
  iif(isnull(AppBy11,true),
  iif(isnull(AppBy10,true),
  iif(isnull(AppBy9,true),
  iif(isnull(AppBy8,true),
  iif(isnull(AppBy7,true),
  iif(isnull(AppBy6,true),
  iif(isnull(AppBy5,true),
  iif(isnull(AppBy4,true),
  iif(isnull(AppBy3,true),
  iif(isnull(AppBy2,true), "", AppBy2), AppBy3), AppBy4), AppBy5), AppBy6), AppBy7), AppBy8), AppBy9, AppBy10), AppBy11) as Result
from entry
```

[image]

Is there any other method which works in lightening speed to arrive the expected result?  I am going to run this query for 6 million data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make use of [COALESCE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql) . It will return first NOT Null column value in the list.

```
SELECT COALESCE(AppBy11, AppBy10,AppBy9,AppBy8,AppBy7,AppBy6,AppBy5,AppBy4,AppBy3,AppBy2,AppBy1) as Result 
FROM entry
```

Comment: Wow so simple and efficient.  Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Happy to help :)